# JSlink: 'Title' and 'Description' returns as Undefined

Tags: list, list-view, jslink

Any help? Other fields such as ID works fine..

```
window.COB = window.COB || {};
window.COB.accordionItem = {
customItemHtml: function (ctx) {

    var accordionItemHtml = "<div title='" + ctx.CurrentItem.Title + "'>" + ctx.CurrentItem.Description;
    accordionItemHtml += "</div>";  
    return accordionItemHtml;
}
};
(function () {
var overrideCtx = {};
overrideCtx.Templates = {};
overrideCtx.Templates.Item = window.COB.accordionItem.customItemHtml;
SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

Comment: Make sure fields added in code exists in selected view as well.

Comment: Yes Deepmala is right. You can only access the fields that are rendered in the current view. If the field is not present in you view then you will get undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine so I added it to a demo site and it works. I would suggest doing as @Deepmala suggested and check that Title and Description fields are included in the current view.